# counting until a certain number down and back up with recursion

Tags: c, function, recursion, countdown, definition

This is a C-assignment. use `void countDownUp(unsigned int k)` to write a recursion to count until a certain number down and then immediately back up. For example, if `k = 3`, the output should be `3 2 1 0 1 2 3`. I already wrote a countDown function

```
void countDown(unsigned int k)
{   
    printf("%d ", k);
    if (k > 0)
        countDown(k-1);
}
```

and also a countUp function. I used this function in my `void countDownUp(unsigned int k)`function like this:

```
void countDownUp(unsigned int k)
{   
    countDown(k);
    static int n=0;
    if(n < k){
        printf("%d ", n+1);
        n++;
        countDownUp(k);
    }
}
```

The output now is `3 2 1 0 1 3 2 1 0 2 3 2 1 0 3 3 2 1 0`I know it doesn't work, but i have no idea how can i adjust it to the right output. Can someone give me some advices? Thank you very much!

Comment: In your first function, try adding another `printf` right after the recursive call. - you don't actually need the second function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use a static variable. The function can be written simpler.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void countDownUp( unsigned int n )
{
    printf( "%u ", n );
    if ( n )
    {
        countDownUp( n - 1 );
        printf( "%u ", n );
    }       
}

int main(void) 
{
    countDownUp( 3 );

    return 0;
}
```

the program output is

```
3 2 1 0 1 2 3
```

As for your function implementation

```
void countDownUp(unsigned int k)
{   
    countDown(k);
    static int n=0;
    if(n < k){
        printf("%d ", n+1);
        n++;
        countDownUp(k);
    }
}
```

then the call within the function

```
countDownUp(k);
```

anew calls `countDown(k);` with the same value of `k` that was passed to the current call of the function `countDownUp` because within the function the value of `k` is not changing..

Also you need to specify the conversion specifier `%u` instead of `%d` because the variable `k` has the type `unsigned int`.

Comment: hii, thanks bro. I know that I made a mess in my functions and I didn't know how to get out of this loop. Your answer is super, now i know how it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Q: What does `CountDownUp()` do in the general case?
A: It prints n twice, with the result of `CountDownUp(n - 1)` in between.

```
void CountDownUp(int n) {
    printf("%d ", n);
    CountDownUp(n - 1);
    printf("%d ", n);
}
```

Q: What's the stop condition?
A: When CountDownUp is called with 0.
Q: What do we do then?
A: Print just once and stop recursion.

```
void CountDownUp(int n) {
    printf("%d ", n);
    if (n == 0) return;
    CountDownUp(n - 1);
    printf("%d ", n);
}
```

[Voila!](https://ideone.com/D3Dott)